# Multiple angular SPA on Single AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, single-page-application

I have a few SPA which are some standard dashboards for each client and they use it occasionally. So I though of moving them to an Amazon S3 bucket. I somewhat got some success with it. I hosted one app added a CNAME to the bucket path and I was there.

I faced a few challenges

1) No SSL by default - Serving on HTTP

2) S3 unable to handle Angular Routes - Duh?

So I moved on to use CloudFront with it providing the SSL to my app. Yes! success with the SSL thing but no improvement on the routes thing.

So I added Lambda@Edge support to convert those 404 errors to my apps index page to handle those reroute but no success again.

So My question is in two parts

1) Can we use Multiple SPA in a Single AWS bucket with SSL and Route handling? if yes what am I missing?

2) Is this even a good Idea to move to AWS S3 to host my SPA. If not then I will move to host them into a Single EC2 instance.

FYI: I'm hosting these apps currently in Azure via App service in a single resource group.

Comment: Why not two cloud front distributions, two buckets  two domains ?

Comment: I thought about it too. but will it be a feasible solution because my dashboards will increase over the period of time and in aws subscription there is a limit of 100 buckets. I think this solution is just an overkill.

Comment: Fair enough. I haven't tried myself . This guy says can, check it out https://vimalpaliwal.com/blog/2018/10/10f435c29f/serving-multiple-s3-buckets-via-single-aws-cloudfront-distribution.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I added Lambda@Edge support to convert those 404 errors to my apps
>   index page to handle those reroute but no success again.

Instead of redirect, fetch the relevant S3 index.html and append to the response.body inside Edge@Lambda.

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;

/**
 * This function updates the response status to 200 and generates static
 * body content to return to the viewer in the following scenario:
 * 1. The function is triggered in an origin response
 * 2. The response status from the origin server is an error status code (4xx or 5xx)
 */

if (response.status >= 400 && response.status <= 599) {
    response.status = 200;
    response.statusDescription = 'OK';
//  Fetch the particular index.html relevant to the SPA from S3 (Based on the request path) and update the response.body
    response.body = 'Body from index.html from S3';
}

// You might need to move the below callback after S3 file fetch success callback.
callback(null, response);
};
```

Reference: [Update Error Status Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-update-error-status-examples)

**Note:** The problem with redirect is that the SPA needs to know the full path with the Angular route for it to load the route. But the redirect will replace it to index.html (Without the relative paths)

Comment: This is what I did in my function.
https://pastebin.com/FMwhyFAZ